# fastest way to cycle through only half the permutations of a sequence?

Tags: python

For instance: When calculating a brute-force solution to the travelling salesman problem, you wouldn't need all the permutations, just the first half of the set of permutations. (the second half are all reversals of the first half).

Basically, I'm trying to get this set:

```
iter_a = itertools.permutations([3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6])
list_a = list(iter_a)
desired_set = list_a[:len(list_a)//2]
```

in the sanest possible way.

Comment: The number of permutations is (n! / (n-r)!); use itertools.islice to efficiently slice a generator.

Comment: @kevingessner That doesn't seem right. It's more reminiscent of "n choose r", i.e. the, but that'd be n! / (r!(n-r)!) and it's not at all relevant here. The number of permutations of n!, half of that is n!/2. What do you intend `r` to be?

Comment: @kevingessner do you know for a fact that the first half of the generator contains no "equal" permutations (where reversals are considered equal)? It seems to me that should be implementation-dependent.

Comment: @shx2: The permutations are returned in lexicographic order; I believe (but am not sure) that reversals of the first half would be sorted into the second half.

Comment: @kevingessner. That's it. Thank you. I appreciate that we keep things polite here, but this is definitely a case of rtfm on my part.

Comment: @shx2. I did a brute-force test of this up to permutations(range(10)), just to make sure. FWIW, >I'm< certain the first half of the generator contains no "equal" permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second half of the permutations are reversals, you can add to your set only the ones with the lowest first member:

```
from itertools import permutations

iter_a = permutations([3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6])

desired_set = set()

for it in iter_a:
if it[0] < it[-1]:
    desired_set.add (it)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still iterate through the entire list of permutations?

Comment: Yes, but only to produce the desired permutation, not to do all the other calculatons with them.